# Urxvt: perl extension '...' not found in perl library search path

Tags: ubuntu, rxvt

I have installed `urxvt` in ubuntu 16.04, and getting this error:

```
$ sudo aptitude install rxvt-unicode 
[....]
$ urxvt
urxvt: perl extension '...' not found in perl library search path
urxvt: perl extension '...' not found in perl library search path
```

I added also the following line in `.Xresources` but that did not help either.

```
URxvt.perl-lib: /usr/bin/perl
```

Not much help on the web. How can I get rid of this warning message?

Comment: Regarding the `.Xresources` being ignored: Did you run `xrdb -merge ~/.Xresources` before starting `urxvt`? It is required for changes in `.Xresources` to take effect.

Comment: Ok, helped, with xrdb, but the perl warning is still there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reinstalled `rxvt-unicode`, `perl`, upgraded all packages to the latest available versions and restarted the system. Removed the `.Xresources` (`.Xdefaults`) file. The warning message disappeared.